# Discord.js v13 , Read status of users and give/remove roles

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im trying to make bot check status of users, when they have discord.gg/ or .gg/ on status give a role, and if they take it out remove it

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get('910192386267840513');
const member = newPresence.member;
const activities = member.user.presence.activities[0];

if (activities && (activities.state.includes('.gg/') || activities.state.includes('discord.gg/'))) {
    return newPresence.member.roles.add(role);
}
else if (member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
    newPresence.member.roles.remove(role);
}});
```

This is the error it shows

```
    const activities = member.user.presence.activities[0];
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'activities')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User`s no longer have `presence`s. You will need to use the `GuildMember` to get the presence

```js
const activities = member.presence.activities[0]
```

Comment: Oh thank you! but it just works one time do i need to loop it?

Comment: What do you mean 1 time? The event only runs once?

Comment: Yes, it only tracks the first update

Comment: Does the event run though? Put `console.log("Running")` at the top of the callback to make sure

Comment: yeah it logs, but then it shows this error     `if (activities && (activities.state.includes('.gg/') || activities.state.includes('discord.gg/'))) {
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'includes')`

Comment: Use optional chaining (`?.`) - `if (activities?.state?.includes('.gg/') || activities?.state?.includes('discord.gg/')))`

Comment: Really really thank you! I've been working on this thing like for 3 days.